# How can I find the maximum of a function with an unknown n parameters?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I have been thinking about it for several days and still have not solved it completely. This is the problem:

My formula: Outcome=$(a_1*b_1)+(a_2*b_2)+(a_3*b_3)...+(a_n*b_n),$ where $0\le a\le 1,$ $0\le b\le1, ~~a+b\le 1, ~~a_1+a_2+a_3...+a_n\le 1.$

I would like to find the maximum of this function based on the value of n. Just by trying out different numbers, I have found that the maximum should be (n-1)/n, but I have not been able to prove it mathematically yet. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: what is $a$? is it a vector? does $0\leq a \leq 1$ means it is bounded by $0$ and $1$ element wise?

Comment: Finding the maximum of a multivariable function (you say there are $n$ parameters) is naturally more difficult than the single-variable function cases.  In this case you have some restrictions on the parameters.  But you should try to clarify the problem.  I'm guessing the $n$ parameters are $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ since you say that there are $n$ parameters, and then $b_i$'s would be fixed.  But that's just guesswork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $0\leq a_i\leq 1$, we have from $a_i+b_i\leq 1$ that

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^na_i(1-a_i).$$

Next assume $\sum_ia_i=x\in[0,1]$. Then use

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{n^2},$$

we obtain

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\leq x-\frac{x^2}{n}.$$

The right-hand side is monotonically increasing over $x\in[0,\frac{n}{2}]$. Therefore it is bounded by its endpoint value at $x=1$ so long as $n\geq 2$. Therefore

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}.$$

For all three inequalities to take equal sign, we have $b_i=1-a_i$, $a_i=\frac{x}{n}$ and $x=1$. Therefore $a_i=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_i=\frac{n-1}{n}$. Since equality is achievable, the upper bound is the maximum.

Comment: $\sum_ia_i$ is supposed to be $\le 1$, not $=1$.

Comment: I assumed $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=1$. In fact the condition is $\leq 1$. You can change it to $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=x\in[0,1]$, go through the same process and then try to maximize the upper bound as a function of $x$. Then you'll see the maximum is achieved at $x=1$.

Comment: But when you go through the same process with $x$, then you get the upper bound $1-x^2/n$, which is larger than $1-1/n$.

Comment: No you should get $x-\frac{x^2}{n}$ The function is monotonically increasing for $x\leq\frac{n}{2}$. So long as $n\geq 2$, the argument holds.

Comment: The math looks prettier without the $x$. But should I really edit it?

Comment: Ok, got it. No, I think it is now fine. It's in the comments. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

it's just an application of the [inequality of Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

You have just to remark that we have this :

$a_1\geq a_2 \cdots \geq a_n$

And

$b_1\leq b_2 \cdots \leq b_n$

Finally conclude .